# Python Modulo arithmetic (remainder) of a fraction

Tags: python, fractions, modular-arithmetic

For the given problem, [Modular Fractions](https://nrich.maths.org/2039):

[image]

the result is: 2 because

[image]

and when x is **2** we have (4%3=1)

Question: is there a method in python that does this with fractions? I have tried `Fraction(1,2) % 3` but the result is

```
> Fraction(1,2)
```

Comment: Hey @adhg, can you clarify your question slightly? Expected output of .5%3 would be .5, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586595/finding-modular-of-a-fraction

Comment: @PeterDolan % 3 is _technically_ not the same as mod 3, in fractional mod it becomes 1 (mod 3) = 2x or essentially 1 % 3 = 2x % 3, which means 1 = 2x % 3 would be our answer

Comment: @Priansh Shah correct and thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of modular arithmetic functionality being available in major (common) scientific computing packages, but check out this modular arithmetic python class definition source code from Dr. Harrington of Loyola University:

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/331/code/mod_arith.py